# Why my votes count doesn't increase?

Tags: support, up-votes

Yesterday I had 291 votes in total (261 up + 30 down, something like that). When I visited [my Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-gonul) today, I had only 253:

[image]

What the heck is going on here?

If my votes don't come back, I will kill myself.

[image]

Comment: Before killing yourself, please think about voting some more, so you can get the counter back to 291 (or even higher).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like, you upvoted the same person continuously more than 5 or 6 times, that probably hit vote fraud mechanisms, and probably all the votes to that person got cleared retroactively.

Comment: You meant "upvoted the same Person" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Probably questions/answers that got deleted - when this happens, all votes on them "disappear".

As far as I know, there is a weekly job that clean the place up and delete questions with negative votes that have no answer, maybe even with zero votes.

So as yesterday new week started, I guess that job kicked into action.

Now you say "but **I** upvoted" - good point, do you have habit of "pity voting" questions with -1 to bring them back to 0? If not I'm also at a loss here.

Comment: If that is true, I shouldn't have any downvotes on [my SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/213464/s-mark).

Comment: Impossible, they are **Jon Skeet** answers. They can't deleted. They only disappear for a while :)

Comment: @YOU you have only 1

Comment: @Shadow, yeah, that 1 is on deleted post, and that shouldn't be exist.

Comment: @Soner you say you upvote only Jon Skeet? That's not good, the system might think you're his sockpuppet and remove your votes.

Comment: @YOU when it was deleted? Maybe that display takes some time to refresh?

Comment: Imm, I did around 2 weeks when I first Joined, and I am not doing downvoting around 1 year I think. :-)

Comment: @YOU do you have link to the question you downvoted? Sure it got deleted, not closed?

Comment: @Shadow, nope, I was looking for that actually. One thing I am sure is that -1 is not in my /reputation page, so it is on deleted one most likely.